# Unknown style sheet in firefox browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I just upload my web application from local machine to my server, however, my problem is that when I open it in firefox browser, it seem it does not apply any style. When I view source and click on the link, style sheet was linked correctly.

But when I open it in chrome browser, it was styled correctly.

Here is my main style sheet path used in my website [mainstyle.css](http://ads.mystudies.info/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.mystudies.info/ads/css/mainstyle.css">
```

And my [web site:](http://ads.mystudies.info/)

Please help me, thanks

Comment: I just ran it on chrome, and it seems that ad blocker is blocking a number of your style sheets (i don't know why). Do you have ad block on firefox?

Comment: It could be the `ads` folder that AdBlockPlus doesn't like, and therefore blocks it - `/ads/css/`

Comment: Maybe you just need to clear your cache in Firefox, press Ctrl + F5  when your page is loaded to clear the cache and reload the page.

Comment: You use the word `banner_ads`, `ads`, `topads`, `latestAds`. A lot of ad blockers will look for these keywords and block them, rendering the site pretty much useless. Either rename these, or disable any adblockers you have installed.

Comment: @DylanCorriveau, yes right, I use ads block add on in firefox. Just tried disable it, and it works fine. Please make it answer, I can mark it. Thanks

Comment: It's probably not the reason but you have this malformed tag in your source code: <labe>Search for:</lable>

Comment: how can I make it not conflict with Ads Block Plus? this website is all about advertisement, if I rename it, it does not make sense.. any advise please, thanks

Comment: Changing the subdomain (if possible) should help. Firefox adblock has an explicit rule for //ads.

Comment: it's a bit better now after changing sub domain, @Fels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, I found that it is the problem with Add Block Plus firefox add on extension. What I have to do is to rename sub-domain and some folders and files to something else beside ***ads***. And it works just fine. Thanks for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

It looks ok in my firefox - is it a caching issue - perhaps try ctrl-f5 a few times. If that does not work, then use firebug to see what is going on, check the network info to make sure it has downloaded the css, and check the console to make sure there are no errors